# How to restrict a Google API Key to an PhoneGap "Android App"

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, phonegap

I am trying to restrict a Google Maps API key so that they will only load on a specific Android app. If I use no restriction then the key works fine in the App, so I am 100% sure that the key is correct.

However when I add the restrictions to the API key in the Google Console then the maps stop loading on the app. I am following the correct instructions for restricting access to a specific package name (com.appname) and the correct finger print is used too.

This is a PhoneGap/Cordova app, so isn't a native Android App. Is this the reason why the restriction is not working?

Comment: For hybrid apps you probably need HTTP referrer restriction with file:// protocol. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key-restrictions

Comment: @xomena Post your comment as an answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

I literally cite the official documentation, based on @xomena comment:

> Before moving your app or website to production, you should secure
>   your API key. Keys for the Maps JavaScript API use the HTTP referrers
>   (web sites) key restriction. [Learn more about keys and credentials](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem).
>
> To add web browser restrictions to an existing, generic API key, do
>   the following:
>
> 1. Go to the Credentials page of the Google API Console.
> 2. Select the project that contains the API key you want to edit.
> 3. On the Credentials page, from the list of API keys, select the name of the API key to edit the details of the key.
> 4. In the Key restriction section of the page, select HTTP referrers (web sites), follow the on-screen instructions to set referrers, then click Save.

Comment: For android app, referrer is `__file_url__//android_asset/www/index.html`, and `__file_url__//android_asset/www/index.html#/*` if you use hash routing

Comment: How is this supposed to be a restriction? I could copy a stolen API key in any app and it will work

Comment: "
How is this supposed to be a restriction? I could copy a stolen API key in any app and it will work – Cristian Traìna Dec 12 '18 at 17:05
" Cristian is right but at least who copies it should issue an app (and not just create an html page) and would be possible  to track him/her through the store. So.... not definitive but better than nothing...

Comment: @piotr_cz  what would the URL be for an iOS app?

Comment: I knew this could work but I always had the referrer url incorrect.  piotr_cz answer did the trick.  But I now need the iOS referrer url to help lock it down to my app on iOS.  As @lui said, its not secure, but its better than nothing.